# how to update the current map with some processing on it in jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I am working with groovy DSL or Jenkins groovy, my current map looks like this

```
def tenants = [
    [
        "tenantId" : "abc1234-qwe122-zaqw-k456",
        "instances" : [
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12456",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.42"    
            ],
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12678",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.43"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "tenantId" : "bc1234-qwe122-zaqw-k233",
        "instances" : [
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12345",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.40"
            ],
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12123",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.41"
            ]
        ]
    ],
]
```

Each tenants has two instances it can be more as well and each instance has a status Active or standby.
I have a function called getTenatnStatus() with me which provides the status of the tenant whether it is active or stand by

I can go over each instance and gather the info whether they are active or not.

```
node("aws"){
    
    stage("getTenantData"){
        tenants.each{
            println(it)    
            it.instances.each{
                println(it)
                //check the tenant status
                def tenantStatus = checktenantsNodeStatus(it.id)
                println(tenantStatus)
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

from above code I can get the status but I want to add the status in the original map, any suggestion how can we do it.
It should look as below

```
def tenants = [
    [
        "tenantId" : "abc1234-qwe122-zaqw-k456",
        "instances" : [
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12456",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.42",
                "status" : "Active"
            ],
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12678",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.43",
                "status" : "Standby"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "tenantId" : "bc1234-qwe122-zaqw-k233",
        "instances" : [
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12345",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.40",
                "status" : "Active"
            ],
            [
                "id" : "i-abc12123",
                "ip" : "101.20.30.41",
                "status" : "Standby"
            ]
        ]
    ],
]
```